# How to work with dynamic forms on backend?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, orm, formbuilder

I want to implement [angularjs-form-builder](http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/#/forms/1/view) in my app which is built on Ruby on Rails/MySQL -  I'm already searching for last few days, but I can't find any information how people work with something like this.

I was thinking about creating few tables:

## Structure

### 1. Form table

```
ID           NAME

1           People
```

### 2. Form fields table

```
 ID         FORM_ID  FIELD_TITLE    FIELD_TYPE  FIELD_REQUIRED

 1             1      First name     textfield        1

 2             1        Gender        radio           0
```

### 3. Options table

```
ID    FIELD_ID    OPTION_TITLE
1        2           Male

2        2           Female
```

## Data

### 2. Row table

```
ID      CREATED_AT
1     2014-05-27 09:21
2     2014-05-27 09:21
```

### 1. Fields Data table

```
ID   ROW_ID    FIELD_ID    FIELD_VALUE
1       1          1            Tom
2       2          1            Michael
3       1          2             2
4       2          2            NULL
```

(In the Fields Data Table ID 3 -> FIELD_VALUE 2 - I mean it would save ID from Options Table

The most important for me is posibility to work with data in this forms as with normal table, like MS Excel or Podio.

Do you have any idea, any known implementation or any other source to get some information what is the best way to implement it? My structure of tables is just idea I think there are exists better implementation, but I can't find it.

Thank you a lot!

David

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with a similar situation.
Here is what I did!

Use 3 tables:

1. Form
2. Fields
3. Values

Schema for the tables could be:

**Form :** 
id: integer 
name: varchar

**Fields :** 
id: integer 
name: varchar 
data_type: varchar 
field_options: varchar   (Here you can store the option values in comma separated format) 
form_id: integer

**Values :** 
id: integer 
form_id: integer 
field_id: integer 
value: text/varchar

Comment: How did you recognize more rows in one form in Values table?

Comment: By foreign keys form_id and field_id!